# How to show a range of scale values when plotting means on bar chart in R

Tags: r, range, bar-chart

I am creating bar charts in R displaying individuals' mean scores and their cohort score in various scales. However, I also want to show the range for individual item scores for the scale.

For example, if I have a mean score of 3 on a scale consisting of 5 items with a 5-point Likert scale, I want to also see whether my individual item ratings ranged from 1-5 (meaning I was all over the place, averaging 3), or 2-4 (meaning I was more consistently scoring near 3).

Initially I was just going to do error bars, but I need it to show the range of scores, not standard error or confidence interval. I'm using ggplot2 and need to ideally stick with this R package due to some of the other coding I need it for.

```
# Make some data
dat <- data.frame(Item1=c(1,2,2,4,5), Item2=c(3,3,1,5,2), Item3=c(1,5,5,4,5), 
                  Item4=c(1,4,3,4,2), Item5=c(3,2,3,4,3))

# Find mean scores
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  dat$ScaleMean[i] <- round(rowMeans(dat, na.rm=T)[i],2)  
}

# Find cohort mean
dat$CoScaleMean <- round(mean(dat$ScaleMean, na.rm=T), 2)

# Add participant IDs
dat$ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)

# Create long data format
dat.long3 <- melt(dat, id.vars=c('ID'), 
                 measure.vars=c('ScaleMean', 'CoScaleMean'))

# Rename variable and value columns
colnames(dat.long3)[c(2,3)] <- c('Scale', 'Score')

# Bar chart
dat.long3 %>% 
  filter(ID == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Scale, y=Score)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Scale, y=Score, fill=Scale), stat = 'identity', width=.9, alpha=1, position='dodge') +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle(label='Scale Name') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 5, 1), limits = c(0, 5), expand=c(0,0)) +  
  scale_x_discrete(labels=element_blank()) +    
  scale_fill_manual(label=paste0(c('Your Score', 'Cohort Score')), values=c('gold', 'darkorange')) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=Scale, label=Score, y=1), size=5, color='#000000')
```

This is for another individual who is requesting a visual representation in the chart (not a table) and needs to keep it in bar chart form (no box plots, etc.). I'm not sure what other options there are to achieve this, if any? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom label with the `glue` package and call that in `geom_text`. Starting after `dat$ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(glue)

dat <- dat %>% 
  nest(items = Item1:Item5) %>% 
  mutate(min = map_dbl(items, min), 
         max = map_dbl(items, max),
         ScaleMean = glue("{ScaleMean} [{min}-{max}]"),
         CoScaleMean = glue("{CoScaleMean} [{min}-{max}]")) %>% 
  select(ID, ScaleMean, CoScaleMean)

# Create long data format
dat.long3 <- melt(dat, id.vars=c('ID'), 
                  measure.vars=c('ScaleMean', 'CoScaleMean'))

dat.long3 <- dat.long3 %>% 
  separate(value, into = c("value", "range"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value))

# Rename variable and value columns
colnames(dat.long3)[c(2,3)] <- c('Scale', 'Score')

# Bar chart
dat.long3 %>% 
  mutate(label = glue("{Score} {range}")) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(ID == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Scale, y=Score)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Scale, y=Score, fill=Scale), stat = 'identity', width=.9, alpha=1, position='dodge') +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle(label='Scale Name') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 5, 1), limits = c(0, 5), expand=c(0,0)) +  
  scale_x_discrete(labels=element_blank()) +    
  scale_fill_manual(label=paste0(c('Your Score', 'Cohort Score')), values=c('gold', 'darkorange')) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, reverse = TRUE)) +
  geom_text(aes(x=Scale, label=label, y=1), size=5, color='#000000')
```

Comment: Thanks. I kinda see where you're going, but I get the error: could not find "map_dbl".  When I search in the packages area, it doesn't even come up.

Comment: Apologies! `map_dbl` is from the `purrr` package, which I've now loaded in the edited response.

Comment: I think I remember using that function now that you mentioned purrr. So, now when I run the code, I get: Error in map_dbl(items, min) : object 'items' not found. If I /only/ run .... dat <- dat %>% nest(items = Item1:Item5). .... the code works, but it isn't recalling the name in the mutate lines.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure what's happening. Everything renders here: http://rpubs.com/daranzolin/so-reprex

Comment: That's weird. Might be my version of R. I'll keep picking at it to see if I can find a work around.

Comment: I actually think it might be your version of the tidyr package. It went through a pretty large update recently.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by just using dat$data instead of the name items. Good to know about the package update.